# String concatenation VS string format

Tags: delphi

What is the best approach, simple string concatenation or `string.format`?

For instance, what is the better to use:

```
 s:=v1+' '+v2
```

or

```
s:=format('%S %S',[v1,v2])
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depends on your criteria for "best".  If all you're doing is concatenating two strings, I'd go with the + operator.  It's obvious what you're trying to do and easy to read, and it's a little bit faster because it doesn't have to use variants.  (Have you looked at what `format` actually does under the hood? it's kinda scary!)

The major advantage of `format` is that it lets you make a single string and store it somewhere, such as in a text file or a **resourcestring**, and gather other parameters later.  This makes it useful for more complex tasks.  But if all you need to do is stick two strings together, it's kinda overkill IMO.

Comment: Usually "best" in the end comes down to "Do I understand why I wrote the code this way 3 months from now?".

Answer (score 10):

Format works with internationalization, making it possible to localize your app. Concatenation does not. Hence, I favor format for any display which may have to be produced in a culture-dependent manner.

Update: The reason format works for internationalization is that not all languages express everything in the same order. A contrived example would be:

```
resourcestring
    sentence = ' is ';

var
    subject = 'Craig';
    adjective = 'helpful';
begin
   WriteLn(subject + sentence + adjective + '!');
```

This works, and I can customize with a resourcestring, but in Spanish I would write, "¡Qué servicial es Craig!" The resourcestring doesn't help me. Instead I should write:

```
resourcestring
    sentence = '%S is %S!'; // ES: '¡Qué %1:S es %0:S!'
```

Comment: You might want to explain that statement, it's probably not obvious to a lot of Delphi users why Format works with i18n.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a third option:

```
s:=Concat(V1,V2);
```

Comment: That is identical to s := V1 + V2; Concat is a compiler "magic" function that is collapsed to call the same internal helper as <str> + <str>.

Comment: While it's identical behind the scenes, I find this easier to read in code than the "+" operator, especially with long strings or multiple concatenations.  This goes back to Mason's practical point of what's "best".

Answer (score 2):

I use:

```
s := v1 + ' ' + v2;
```

It's clearest and easiest to understand.

That is the most important thing.

You may find a construct that is marginally more efficient, e.g. using TStringBuilder in Delphi 2009. If efficiency is of utmost importance, then do what's necessary in the two or three most critical lines. Everywhere else, use code and constructs that are clear and easy to understand.