# UPDATE record using SET and WHERE for ACCESS table

Tags: ms-access, delphi-7

I'm trying to allow record updates on a simple MS Access table (tblCustomer).  To edit a record, and for the SET clause, the user selects a field name from a combo box (cboSetField) and enters text into associated text box (txtSet).  For the WHERE clause, the user selects a field from a combo box (cboWhereField) and enters text into associated text box (txtWhere).  So, essentially, what i have in the code which follows is something akin to:

UPDATE tblCustomers
SET [cboSetField] = [txtSet]
WHERE [cboWhereField] = [txtWhere]

Here is the actual Delphi code:

```
procedure TfrmDeleteCustomer.cmdUpdateClick(Sender: TObject);
var WhereFieldSelection,WhereTextSelection, SetFieldSelection, SetTextSelection :string;
begin

WhereFieldSelection:=cboWhereField.Text;
WhereTextSelection:=txtWhere.Text;
SetFieldSelection:=cboSetField.Text;
SetTextSelection:=txtSet.Text;

adoQuery1.SQL.Clear;
adoQuery1.SQL.Add('UPDATE tblCUSTOMER');
adoQuery1.SQL.Add('SET (:SetFieldSelection) = (:SetTextSelection)');
adoQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE (:WhereFieldSelection) = (:WhereTextSelection)');
adoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('SetFieldSelection').Value:= SetFieldSelection;
adoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('SetTextSelection').Value:= SetTextSelection;
adoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('WhereFieldSelection').Value:= WhereFieldSelection;
adoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('WhereTextSelection').Value:= WhereTextSelection;
adoQuery1.ExecSQL;
adoQuery1.Close;

txtSet.Text:='';
txtWhere.Text:='';
cboSetField.Text:='';
cboWhereField.Text:='';
adoQuery1.SQL.Clear;
adoQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tblCUSTOMER');
adoQuery1.Open;
end;
```

Now, when i run the program, i get the following error message:

> Exception Class Raised: Syntax Error in UPDATE Statement

What am i doing wrong here?

Using: Delphi 7, ADO connection, MS ACCESS 2003.

Comment: What does the entire output of the SQL query look like? Are any spaces being excluded between UPDATE, SET, or WHERE, or is there anything strange in any of the entered fields or criteria?

Comment: You might have to provide the actual field name instead of :SetFieldSelection  and :WhereFieldSelection. I don't think field names can be parameterized. Only the values can be. Replace :SetFieldSelection and :WhereFieldSelection with actual field names, remove their appropriate parameters and see how it works.

Comment: Yes zedfoxus, when i removed the parameterised field names, and directly entered an actual field name, it works.  My question now is, then, how can i design my form to accommodate for all possible field updates?  The combobox allowed the user to pick a field and enter a value beside it.  One idea, would to have a textbox for EVERY field i suppose!?

Comment: You could keep the combobox and in code use a case statement or a series of if/else statements to ensure the field selected in the combobox is used in the SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in most database APIs such as ADO (or PDO for PHP or cursors for Python) parameters in SQL queries involve passing **values** in a query, not passing **field names** which are structural components to the table.

Consider dynamically [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400502/string-concatenation-vs-string-format) the SQL string that then uses parameterized values:

```
 adoQuery1.SQL.Add(format('UPDATE tblCUSTOMER SET %S = :SetTextSelection', [SetFieldSelection]));
 adoQuery1.SQL.Add(format('WHERE %S = :WhereTextSelection', [WhereFiedSelection])); 
 adoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('SetTextSelection').Value:= SetTextSelection; 
 adoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('WhereTextSelection').Value:= WhereTextSelection;
 adoQuery1.ExecSQL;
```